# Unable to type anything on my mac when using hoblink

Tags: macbook-pro

I am logging onto a Hoblink remote access that uses Java via the browser to connect to my work laptop as well. I get onto the log in screen and unable to type the username or password. Seems like the keyboard is locked at the point.Please help.